# Ajax can't redirect to a thank you URL after submitting data to two endpoints

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form, and I am sending data from it to the database and to a Zapier webhook after clicking the "Complete" button. It works, I can see the data in database as well as in Google Sheet(from Zapier). But I want to redirect to a website after successfully submitting the data and it is not doing that. The code is:

```html
<button id="submit-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning new-sbm-btn" type="button" onClick="send_to_db(); submit_to_zapier();">Complete</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function send_to_db() {
    var Username = $('#Username').val();
    var ShippingAddress = $('#Address').val();
    var ShippingProvince = $('#Province').val();
    var ShippingPostalCode = $('#PostalCode').val();
    
    var arr = {
      Username: SUsername,
      Address: SShippingAddress,
      Province: SProvince,
      PostalCode: SPostalCode
    };
    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'save_data.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(arr),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        window.location.href = '';
      }
    });
  }

  function submit_to_zapier() {
    var Username = $('#Username').val();
    var ShippingAddress = $('#Address').val();
    var ShippingProvince = $('#Province').val();
    var ShippingPostalCode = $('#PostalCode').val();
    
    var arr = {
      Username: SUsername,
      Address: SShippingAddress,
      Province: SProvince,
      PostalCode: SPostalCode
    };
    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'proxy.php?csurl=https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/8542104',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(arr),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        window.location.href = "http://dacasa.it";
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

I can't figure out what's wrong thus need a little help in it. I am at beginner level at JQuery. Also, I see the following warning in the browser console:

> jquery.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

The warning in your console is because you're using `async: false` which is very bad practice.

A better approach to this would be to return the jqXHR objects created by the `$.ajax()` calls in your functions, then perform your redirect once they have both completed asynchronously. Try this:

```html
<button id="submit-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning new-sbm-btn" type="button">Complete</button>
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#submit-button').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
      Username: $('#Username').val(),
      Address: $('#Address').val(),
      Province: $('#Province').val(),
      PostalCode: $('#PostalCode').val()
    }

    $.when(send_to_db(data), submit_to_zapier(data)).then(() => {
      window.location.assign('http://dacasa.it');
    });
  });
});

function send_to_db(data) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'save_data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}

function submit_to_zapier(data) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'proxy.php?csurl=https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/8542104',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the rewrite up but it is still not redirecting. Same as before...the data is submitting but doesn't redirect after that.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also, is the submit `<button>` element within a form?